# Is there a string.prototype.matchAll ES5 safe alternative?

Tags: javascript, regex, string-matching, ecmascript-5

Just found out that `matchAll` is not supported by many browser versions.

Is there an ES5 safe alternative for the `string.prototype.matchAll` method?

```
const regexp = /(?:\[(.*?)\]\((.*?)\))|([^[]+)/g;
const matchedElements = Array.from(value.matchAll(regexp));
```

Comment: `.matchAll` is just syntactic sugar, use `exec` in a loop to get all matches you need.

Comment: Nice! I will do that. Thank you!

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew apparently it's a bit more than syntactic sugar as it doesn't touch the `.lastIndex`, but normally that shouldn't matter.